# Build this statement with ActiveRecord on Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

Suppose you have these 3 models: Store, Province and Region

Where occur these relationships:

store belongs_to province

province belongs_to region

store has_one region through province

Well, I'd like to build such a SQL query within ActiveRecord:

```
SELECT a.*, c.* FROM stores AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN provinces AS b ON a.province_id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN regions AS c ON b.region_id = c.id
ORDER BY c.name, a.name
```

But still I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I found the solution:

```
Store.all :joins => [:province => :region], :order => "regions.name ASC, stores.name asc"
```

Comment: I would expect this to generate INNER JOINS, not OUTER JOINS like you showed in your question.